# How to stringify a complex object where some values are arrays containing functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am writing a custom `useAxios` hook. I want the `axios` request config [object](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config) to be in the dependency array of my `useEffect`. However, that object contains functions within arrays. I am trying to find a way to stringify the `axios` request config object so it can be properly diffed by the `useEffect`.

Tried using `JSON.stringify` with a custom [replacer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter) but the [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString) method is too literal and keeps margin spacing and so two seemingly identical functions will be evaluated as unique because of spacing.

Here is my `JSON.stringify` with a custom replacer:

```js
JSON.stringify(param1, (key, value) => {
  if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    return value.map(func => func.toString());
  }
});
```

I am looking for these two objects to be evaluated as equal regardless of spacing:

1.

```js
{
  url: 'https://reqres.in/api/things/1',
  responseType: 'json',
  transformResponse: [
    function test(param) {
      return param;
    },
  ],
}
```

2.

```js
  {
    url: 'https://reqres.in/api/things/1',
    responseType: 'json',
    transformResponse: [
      function test(param) {
        return param;
      },
    ],
  }
```

and these two objects to evaluated as unique:

1.

```js
{
  url: 'https://reqres.in/api/things/1',
  responseType: 'json',
  transformResponse: [
    function test(param) {
      return param;
    },
  ],
}
```

2.

```js
{
  url: 'https://reqres.in/api/things/1',
  responseType: 'json',
  transformResponse: [
    function test2(param) {
      return param;
    },
  ],
}
```

Comment: Two distinct objects will never be `==` or `===` to each other regardless of contents.

Comment: Right, and I am looking for two objects that contain the same contents to be evaluated as equal. Typically, I would use `lodash`'s [`isEqual`](https://lodash.com/docs/#isEqual) for this or `JSON.stringify`, but since some object property values contain an array containing functions, it's a bit more complex.

Comment: @jaypee Just minify the functions

Comment: Oh I didn’t try that. Good idea. Do you have any libraries in mind for minifying at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's suggested https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14476 you can use `useRef` to save previous config and use `compare(prevConfig, config)` as a dependency:

```
function useAxios(config) {
  const [prevConfig] = useRef(null); 
  useEffect(() => {
    ... 
    prevConfig.current = config; 
  }, [isDeepEqual(config, prevConfig)]);
}
```

Where `isDeepEqual` maybe custom comparator or just helped from underscore/lodash.